# Complex Mongodb query inside loop?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am creating a web portal to visualise a fibre optic network.
I am working with optic cables connected together and the following schema represents the connections:

```
var Splice = new Schema({
    cable_a: String, //reference of cable_a
    cable_b: String, //reference of cable_b
    fibre_a: Number, //fibre of cable a
    fibre_b: Number //fibre of cable b
 });
```

I know the reference of my first cable and its fibre and I would like to be able to recreate the route of the circuit by going through each connection, fibre by fibre. The point is if my reference equal cable_a, cable_b becomes the reference of my next research till I complete the circuit...

```
while ( //circuit not complete... ) {
    Splice.find({$or: [{$and: [{cable_a:ref}, {fibre_a:fibre}]},{$and: [{cable_b:ref}, {fibre_b:fibre}]}]}, function(docs){
        if ( ref == cable_a && f == fibre_a ) {
            ref = cable_b;
            f = fibre_b;
            req.circuit.push(docs);
        } else if ( ref == cable_a && f == fibre_a ) {
            ref = cable_b;
            f = fibre_b;
            req.circuit.push(docs);
        }
    }
}
```

I hope someone can help me. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) module, specifically [waterfall](https://github.com/caolan/async#waterfall) method.

Comment: Thanks. It could work If I knew the total number of cables in the circuit but I don't have this information. I am looking for a way to fill in my circuit by querying mongo using the same request (with different parameters) multiple times.

Comment: oh, missed that. try https://github.com/caolan/async#whilsttest-fn-callback than.